# lat/lng ot returned by google map

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I write a function for getting latitude/longitude which is working fine for address 
"150 London Wall London, London, EC2Y 5HN, United Kingdom".
But sometimes address will come as below 
"Calle Pío Verdú, Vélez-Málaga, 29700, Malaga, Spain".
Contains language specific characters. in that case error comes and no value returned by google map.

I am passing these locations to function which contains

$address = urlencode($location);
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false";

and then via curl i got the result

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it is because the `$location` variable is not UTF-8 encoded. Check the origin of this variable to be sure that it is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @user2485518: From where come the `$location` content? (database, hardcoded,...)

Comment: @user2485518: take a look at this link: http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/04/09/87.aspx